# VIrtualBox Ubuntu 20-04 Installation boot stuck

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox 6.1 and Ubuntu 20.04. I have set up the machine with defualt settings, after initial boot it remains in the boot screen, never gets to initial setup. Anyone encountered this issue before.

[image]

Log File:

```
00:00:00.003010 main     VirtualBox COM Server 6.1.16 r140961 win.amd64 (Oct 16 2020 16:33:17) release log
00:00:00.003013 main     Log opened 2020-12-10T11:59:56.053685500Z
00:00:00.003013 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.003017 main     OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:00.003018 main     OS Release: 10.0.19041
00:00:00.003018 main     OS Service Pack: 
00:00:00.021064 main     DMI Product Name: Latitude 5410
00:00:00.030759 main     DMI Product Version: 
00:00:00.030767 main     Firmware type: UEFI
00:00:00.030988 main     Secure Boot: VERR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD
00:00:00.030999 main     Host RAM: 15980MB (15.6GB) total, 4110MB (4.0GB) available
00:00:00.031003 main     Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.031003 main     Process ID: 21420
00:00:00.031004 main     Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.085659          VirtualBox: object creation starts
00:00:00.085838          Home directory: 'C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox'
00:00:00.085933          Installed Drivers:
00:00:00.090942            C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxDrv.sys (Version: 6.1.16.40961)
00:00:00.091275            C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxUSBMon.sys (Version: 6.1.16.40961)
00:00:00.091620            C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxNetAdp6.sys (Version: 6.1.16.40961)
00:00:00.091929            C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxNetLwf.sys (Version: 6.1.16.40961)
00:00:00.092663          Loading settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:00.094909          usbLibGetDevices: Starting USB device enumeration
00:00:00.096210          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&33989476&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 6
00:00:00.096257          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&33989476&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 8
00:00:00.096304          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&33989476&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 10
00:00:00.096463          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#ROOT_HUB30#5&11d8eaa2&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 1
00:00:00.096549          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#ROOT_HUB30#5&11d8eaa2&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 2
00:00:00.096597          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#ROOT_HUB30#5&11d8eaa2&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 3
00:00:00.229807          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#VID_0BDA&PID_5413#b&3a775e&0&3#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 5
00:00:00.229872          Getting USB descriptor (id 0) failed (dwErr=31) on hub USB#VID_0BDA&PID_5487#a&5083233&0&2#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} port 5
00:00:00.233379          usbLibGetDevices: Found 12 USB devices, 0 captured
00:00:00.233421          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x0a5c, idProduct: 0x5843)
00:00:00.233472          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x1bcf, idProduct: 0x28c4)
00:00:00.233502          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x413c, idProduct: 0xb06e)
00:00:00.233512          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x413c, idProduct: 0xb06f)
00:00:00.233525          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x8087, idProduct: 0x0026)
00:00:00.233550          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x8087, idProduct: 0x0ac9)
00:00:00.233559          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x8087, idProduct: 0x0aca)
00:00:00.233567          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x8087, idProduct: 0x0af1)
00:00:00.360663          HostDnsMonitor: initializing
00:00:00.373693          HostDnsMonitor: updating information
00:00:00.373715          HostDnsMonitor: old information
00:00:00.373716            no server entries
00:00:00.373716            no domain set
00:00:00.373717            no search string entries
00:00:00.373717          HostDnsMonitor: new information
00:00:00.373718            server 1: 192.168.0.1
00:00:00.373718            domain: Home
00:00:00.373719            no search string entries
00:00:00.375625          VD: VDInit finished with VINF_SUCCESS
00:00:00.377040          Loading settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu 20-04\Ubuntu 20-04.vbox" with version "1.16-windows"
00:00:00.378767          VirtualBox: object created
00:00:02.390810          Launched VM: 52402992 pid: 22876 (0x595c) frontend: GUI/Qt name: Ubuntu 20-04
00:00:06.429123          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={70401eef-c8e9-466b-9660-45cb3e9979e4} aComponent={ExtPackManagerWrap} aText={No extension pack by the name 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' was found}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:06.698995          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37
00:00:07.644685          Saving settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu 20-04\Ubuntu 20-04.vbox" with version "1.16-windows"
00:00:48.263560          Saving settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:48.284381          Saving settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:54.524757 ExtPackInst ExtPack: Executing 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxExtPackHelperApp.exe' '--display-info-hack' 'hwnd=0x221c72' 'install' '--base-dir' 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ExtensionPacks' '--cert-dir' 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ExtPackCertificates' '--name' 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' '--tarball' 'C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Local/Temp/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16-140961.vbox-extpack' '--sha-256' '9802482b77b95a954cb5111793da10d009009a4e9a9c4eaa4bd1ae5dafe9db46'
00:00:57.370715 ExtPackInst ExtPack: enmReason=1 iStatus=0 stderr='rcExit=RTEXITCODE_SUCCESS


00:00:57.370718 ExtPackInst '
00:00:57.537162 ExtPackInst ExtPackManager: Found extension pack 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack'.
00:00:57.569096 ExtPackInst ExtPackManager: Successfully installed extension pack 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack'.
00:00:57.569687 ExtPackInst OCI: Local config file 'C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox\oci_config' does not exist
00:00:57.569809 ExtPackInst OCI: Original config file 'C:\Users\Kevin\.oci\config' does not exist
00:00:57.569816 ExtPackInst OCI: Reading profiles finished with status ERROR_SUCCESS
00:00:57.569851 ExtPackInst ExtPack: Created cloud provider 'OCI' (hrc=ERROR_SUCCESS)
00:01:00.539222          Launched VM: 52233840 pid: 19480 (0x4c18) frontend: GUI/Qt name: Ubuntu 20-04
00:01:05.086760          Load [C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ExtensionPacks\Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack\win.amd64\VBoxHostWebcam.DLL] vrc=VINF_SUCCESS
00:01:05.384219          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37
00:05:17.503415          Saving settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu 20-04\Ubuntu 20-04.vbox" with version "1.16-windows"
00:07:06.200842          Saving settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:07:06.221009          Saving settings file "C:\Users\Kevin\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:07:11.768216 main     VirtualBox: object deletion starts
00:07:11.768313 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'C:\Users\Kevin\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu 20-04\Ubuntu 20-04.vdi' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:07:11.769336 main     HostDnsMonitor: shutting down ...
00:07:11.769444 main     HostDnsMonitor: shut down
00:07:11.773025 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:07:11.773289 main     VirtualBox: object deleted
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you attach the Ubuntu desktop ISO image to this configuration?

Comment: increase the base memory (vm ram) allocated to the vm

Comment: @SankalpKotewar Yes I have done that

Comment: @cmak.fr It is at 2GB should it be more, I thought this would be more than enough

Comment: @tester123 can you share the rest of the configurations that you provided to your VM?

Comment: @SankalpKotewar Updated!

Comment: Can you please increase your video memory and make it full 128MB? Also increasing the CPU count to 2+ should help you.

Comment: @SankalpKotewar Same behavior. I have setup ubuntu on virtualbox numerous times and never had any issue before. Are there any known issues with this latest version I wonder. I would expect to be able to at least load the setup screen. Just getting stuck at boot doesnt point to my initial settings I would have thought

Comment: I am unaware of any known issues, I've seen one of my friend successfully running ubuntu 20.04 VM on a Windows 10 machine. Just curious, what OS are you using? And have you set up Ubuntu on Virtual box previously on the same machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117122/discussion-between-tester123-and-sankalp-kotewar).

Comment: I'd ask if you've verified the downloaded .iso. You really should do that, if you've not yet done so. I use VBox daily, many times a day, to do exactly this and it goes off without a hitch. I'd start there, with verifying the .iso.

Comment: Also, give me a screenshot of the "Basic" tab under "Settings"

Comment: @KGIII ISO verified correctly and added basic to question

Comment: Everything looks okay in your VirtualBox settings. So, that shouldn't be the problem. The last place to look is in your BIOS. In there, you should find a couple of virtualization options. Make sure they're both enabled.